# How can I make JavaScript for bulk mockup in photoshop?

Tags: photoshop-script

I am making JavaScript for bulk mockup in photoshop but the script is not running properly.

I wrote the code for bulk mockup for photoshop. the pop up window for it is perfectly fine but it doesn't work accordingly after I input the data with mockup and images folder.

Comment: What errors do you get? Also you need to include your code, so we can help. See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more details.